# Create a function which inputs a file and calculates grade

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

Each line of the file will have the format:

[image]

where

- name is a string
- q1 through q6 are quiz scores (integers)
- a1 through a4 are assignment scores (integers values)
- midterm is midterm score (integer)
- final is final exam score (integer)

For example, if the content of the file looks like this:

[image]

Content of file in text format:

*tom, 10, 20, 0, 100, 0, 100, 70, 80, 90, 0, 80, 85*

*mary, 0, 50, 66, 40, 10, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 80, 85*

*joan, 0, 80, 40, 10, 50, 60, 7, 80, 90, 0, 80, 5*

Note that there may be additional spaces between the entries in each line.

Your function should return a dictionary such as:

[image]

Notes:

- Two of the lowest quizzes should be dropped and the average of the remaining four quizzes is worth 25% of the total grade.
- The lowest assignment score should be dropped and the average of the remaining three assignments is worth 25% of the total grade.
- Midterm and final exams are each 25% of the total grade.

Calculate the total score of the student and if the total score is greater than or equal to 60 (totalscore >= 60) then the student has passed. Notice that the keys (names) and the values (pass or fail) of the dictionary should be all lower cased with no spaces in any of them.

CODE (developed so far):

```
1 def my_final_grade_calculation(filename):
2 file_pointer = open(filename, 'r')
3 data = file_pointer.readlines()
4 for line in data:
5     a=[]
6     q=[]
7     dict_={}
8     name, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, a1, a2, a3, a4, midterm, final =  line.strip().split(',')
9     q=[int(q1),int(q2),int(q3),int(q4),int(q5),int(q6)]
10    a=[int(a1),int(a2),int(a3),int(a4)]
11    int(midterm)
12    int(final)
13    for i in range(0,2):
14        q.remove(min(q))  
15    a.remove(min(a))
16    a_avg=0.0
17    for j in range(0,len(a)):
18        a_avg+=a[j]/len(a)
19    q_avg=0.0
20    for i in range(0,len(q)):
21        q_avg+=q[i]/len(q)
22    final = ((float(q_avg)/4)) + ((float(a_avg)/4)) + ((float(midterm)/4)) + ((float(final)/4))
23    if (final>=60.0):
24        out='pass'
25        return dict_[name]=out
26    else:
27        out='fail'
28        return dict_[name]=out
29
30 #calling function  
31 print(my_final_grade_calculation('filename.txt'))
```

ERROR:

```
invalid syntax: <string>, line 25, pos 31
```

Other than this I am not sure whether my answer iscorrect or not ? Please help.

Comment: As the error says, look at line 25. Which line of code is that? What's at the 31st character?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I have added the row numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works (however, I haven't checked your computations)

```
def my_final_grade_calculation(filename):
    file_pointer = open(filename, 'r')
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    dict_={}
    for line in data:
        #a=[]
        #q=[]
        #dict={}
        name, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, a1, a2, a3, a4, midterm, final =  line.strip().split(',')
        q=[int(q1),int(q2),int(q3),int(q4),int(q5),int(q6)]
        a=[int(a1),int(a2),int(a3),int(a4)]
        #int(midterm)
        #int(final)
        for i in range(0,2):
            q.remove(min(q))  
        a.remove(min(a))
        a_avg=0.0
        for j in range(0,len(a)):
            a_avg+=a[j]/len(a)
        q_avg=0.0
        for i in range(0,len(q)):
            q_avg+=q[i]/len(q)
        final = ((float(q_avg)/4)) + ((float(a_avg)/4)) + ((float(midterm)/4)) + ((float(final)/4))
        if final>=60.0:
            out='pass'
            dict_[name]=out
        else:
            out='fail'
            dict_[name]=out
    return dict_

#calling function  
print(my_final_grade_calculation('filename.txt'))
```

I left some of your code as comments in order to show you the differences. Basically, your original code returned a command, namely setting the value of key `name` to `out` in dictionary `dict_`, instead of returning dictionary `dict_`.
Note, that method `my_final_grade` terminates if a `return` statement is encountered. Hence, your original method stops always with the first line of your text file.

Comment: How to run it for more than 1 line

Comment: the code I gave you runs over the whole file

Comment: No, it didn't. I ran it on my compiler

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your indentation?

Comment: I get the following output for your example: {'joan': 'fail', 'mary': 'pass', 'tom': 'pass'}

Comment: Got it. My bad. Thank you